# Bison: Avoid default construction of semantic values

Tags: c++, bison

I'm using Bison with C++ and the variants option to construct an AST. If I understand it correctly, Bison always default constructs the semantic values (the AST nodes in my case) before I assign something to them with `$$ = ...`. However, I'd like to keep some (actually most) of my AST nodes non-default constructible, because that would leave them in an invalid state. If I allow default construction of every node, I'd have to rely on runtime checks to ensure that every node I'm working with is valid. Is there any way to make Bison not default construct my nodes and only construct them when I do the `$$ = ...` action?

Edit: @Some programmer dude requested an example, so here it is, but it's quite long, so sorry about that.

Suppose the following AST structure:

```
namespace node {
    template <typename T>
    struct component {
        // Not default constructible.
        component (T &&);
        component (component &&);
        component & operator = (T &&);
        component & operator = (component &&);
        ~component ();
        T & get ();
        T const & get () const;
    private:
        T * ptr;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct optional_component {
        // Default constructible:
        optional_component (): ptr{nullptr} {}
        optional_component (T &&);
        optional_component (component &&);
        optional_component & operator = (T &&);
        optional_component & operator = (component &&);
        ~optional_component ();
        T & get ();
        T const & get () const;
        // Need to check for present value before use:
        bool has_value () const { return ptr; }
    private:
        T * ptr;
    };

    struct C {
        int val;
    };

    struct A {
        // Not default constructible, because component<C> is not.
        component<C> bar;
    };

    struct B {
        // Default constructible, because component<C> is too.
        optional_component<C> c;
    }
}

namespace category {

    struct X {
        // Not default constructible,
        // unless the first type of the variant is default constructible,
        // or I provide the default constructor manually.
        std::variant<node::A, node::B> node;
    };

}
```

And the following parser definition:

```
%language "c++"
%define api.value.type variant
%define api.value.automove
%parse-param { category::X & result }

%token A
%token B
%token BB
%token <int> C
%nterm <node::A> node_a
%nterm <node::B> node_b
%nterm <node::C> node_c
%nterm <int> start

%%

start:  node_a   { result = {.node = $node_a}; } |
        node_b   { result = {.node = $node_b}; }
node_c: C        { $$ = {.val = $1};           }
node_a: A node_c { $$ = {.c = $node_c};        }
node_b: B node_c { $$ = {.c = $node_c};        } |
        BB       { $$ = {};                    }
```

The generated parser first tries to default construct the nodes. E.g.:

```
yylhs.value.emplace<node::A>();
```

And only then assigns the value. E.g:

```
yylhs.value.as<node::A>() = {.c = YY_MOVE(yystack_[1].value.as<node::C>())};
```

What I need is to skip the default constructing `emplace` call and actually construct the node with the given child nodes directly.

I've found this in the generated header file:

```
# if 201103L <= YY_CPLUSPLUS
    /// Instantiate a \a T in here from \a t.
    template <typename T, typename... U>
    T& emplace (U&&... u) {
      return *new (yyas_<T> ()) T (std::forward <U>(u)...);
    }
# else
    /// Instantiate an empty \a T in here.
    template <typename T>
    T& emplace () {
        return *new (yyas_<T> ()) T ();
    }

    /// Instantiate a \a T in here from \a t.
    template <typename T>
    T& emplace (const T& t) {
        return *new (yyas_<T> ()) T (t);
    }
# endif
```

So it seems that the `emplace` method is actually meant to be able to construct the final value directly.

Comment: An AST (like most other trees and graphs) normally uses *pointers* to nodes in the tree. It's up to your semantic actions to create the actual nodes in any suitable way.

Comment: Yes, but the semantic values, in my case, represent the nodes directly (in a variant), not pointers to them. And in every node I use a wrapper that represents a node's "component" - implemented with a pointer but not default constructible, or an "optional component" - default constructible to an empty value represented by a `nullptr`. I'd really like to avoid having every such "component" optional.

Comment: Then you should probably redo it as pointers. You're going to need that anyway to build your tree. If the semantic values are objects, you can't get pointers to them as the life-time of those objects will not be long enough.

Comment: I'm allocating the child nodes on the heap before actually inserting them into their parent. It is implemented with pointers, it's just that I use an abstraction around those pointers that basically represents non-nullable pointers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information, as well as some actual code showing it all. It's hard to see what you're doing and what you want to be doing instead with only abstract descriptions. Code do say more than a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the intent of the bison implementation in this case is to avoid the possibility of an uninitialised `variant` value, which would be lead to undefined behaviour because of the nature of a Bison `variant`. The bison `variant` does not record the type of the object it has been initialised with, because that case never occurs during a parse. So as soon as the parser knows which type the stack slot will contain (which is to say, when it decides that it will execute the reduction action), it must initialise the stack slot, and it can only use a default constructor because it hasn't yet executed the reduction action.

A Bison variant object is basically a `union`, not a discriminated union; the `variant` part refers to the fact that the control flow of the program is sufficient to determine the type of the contained object. So there can be no such thing as an uninitialised `variant`. Moreover, since the `variant` has an (implicit) type from the moment of its creation until the moment of its destruction, the type cannot be changed during its lifetime.

So your desired semantics are at odds with this design. That doesn't make your semantics wrong (or, for that matter, bison's), but it does mean that you cannot use a bison `variant` if you want the possibility of an "uninitialised" variant. On the other hand, I'm not sure how you can accomplish this:

> However, I'd like to keep some (actually most) of my AST nodes non-default constructible, because that would leave them in an invalid state. If I allow default construction of every node, I'd have to rely on runtime checks to ensure that every node I'm working with is valid.

The question is, what does it mean for an AST node to be in an invalid state? And how will you know that to be the case without a runtime check? Do you expect it to throw an exception on use or some such? If so, there is definitely a run-time check.

You could implement an invalid state by using a `std::variant` whose first alternative is a default-constructible `InvalidNode` type, or some such, although you'll have to take care that it doesn't become an no-op instead of an error when you try to use the `variant` object. In that case, you could tell Bison to use `std::variant` as a semantic type, although that won't be quite as convenient as using a Bison `variant`.

***Note:*** In a comment (which is not at all the best place to clarify a question) you seem to be saying that your desired variants are always pointers, meaning that the "invalid node" type is essentially a `nullptr`. I'm sure that can be made to work with Bison, but you'll need to do it in a different way than the use of Bison `variant`s. How good a match it is for `std::variant` is not entirely clear to me either :-)

Comment: By invalid state I mean that the node would have all its components default constructed to contain null pointers even though these components are mandatory. My plan was to rely on the fact that the mandatory components cannot be constructed in any way to contain null pointers (default constructed or explicitly from a null pointer), which is enforced at compile time. The idea of having an invalid default constructible node could be helpful though. I'll try to come up with some compromise between my initial requirements and the Bison's functionality.

Comment: @egst: You can use a `std::vector<T>` even if `T` is not default constructible, but there are limitations. One limitation is that you cannot call `resize`. And in effect, that's the situation here: the parser stack is a stack, and a reduction action must push some value onto the stack. At compile time, you can either guarantee that a function pushes a value is pushed onto a stack, or you can guarantee that a function pushes a non-default constructed value. But not both. Bison requires that a value be pushed, so it pushes one. And it can only push a default constructed value.

Comment: If it didn't push a value at all, then it would be dependent on the reduction action doing that. And it's impossible for it to know that that will happen.

Comment: I don't really have any deeper understanding of how the reduction actually works (yet), so I was unaware of that, but now it makes sense. Thank you for the explanation! So simply speaking, the parsing algorithm needs to push something to the stack before it can figure out which action to apply and what to actually assign to the pushed element?

Comment: @egst: The reduction action must have a result, which is the semantic value of the non-terminal being reduced. And that result must be pushed onto the parser stack, so that future reduction actions can use it (with `$n` references). The parsing algorithm doesn't need to push a value before deciding which action to take. But once it has decided an action, it is committed to a certain post-action stack layout. And that can only be achieved if a value is pushed to the stack. So if the parser knew that the action was going to push a value, that would be fine. But how can it know? (cont'd)

Comment: ... The action is a piece of C code which could do basically anything. Even if bison came with a complete C parser (and it doesn't), there's no way to predict what the action will do. So the only plausible solution is to isolate the stack from the action. Bison always pushes a new default-constructed value of the correct type and then arranges for `$$` to be a reference to that value, allowing the parsing action to change the value to the result it wants. And if the action chooses to do nother, no worries. Because there is guaranteed to be some value there.

Answer (score 1):

With helpful explanations from @rici and after some deeper examination of the generated C++ file for the parser, I've found a rather "dirty" solution. I don't think it's a good idea to rely on such a solution, but it works and I'd like to share it:

Before executing the actions specified in the parser definition, Bison pushes some default values to its stack by calling:

```
yylhs.value.emplace< type > ();
```

...where `type` is the semantic value type of the corresponding non-terminal in the parser definition. Only after that, it proceeds to execute the appropriate action that might assign a value to this newly pushed item. Bison has no way of knowing whether any value will be assigned, so it has to push at least this default constructed value. However, if you are sure, that you assign a value in every action, you don't really need these default constructions. So my solution is to simply tweak the generated C++ file by modifying these default constructions to:

```
yylhs.value.emplace< int > ();
```

I do this by simply sticking a line of sed command in my makefile:

```
sed -i 's/yylhs.value.emplace< my_ast_namespace::[^ ]* > ();/yylhs.value.emplace< int > (); \/\/ Modified./g' generated_parser.cpp
```

(Note: The regex relies on the fact that there are always spaces inside the outer `<>` but no spaces in the contained type, otherwise it would be impossible to do with nested templates.)

Now there is no need for a default constructor for my nodes. The pushed value has a wrong type, but in my case, it's not any worse to have an int value in there than to have the correct node with all of its children as null pointers - both will lead to incorrect behaviour.

*I won't accept my answer, since it's really just a "hacky workaround" that might break with different versions of Bison. I also don't want to accept the @rici's answer yet, because it seems that with this experiment I've confirmed, that it is in principle possible to do what I wanted.*

Comment: It's not just a dirty hack. It violates an invariant which bison only checks in some debugging modes (but it's definitely a violation). Try "%define parse.assert" and see what happens. (Of course, you're under no obligation to accept bison's rules :-). But they have their reasons.)